# Can I use standfordCore Natural Language Processing Libraries in Android?

Tags: android, nlp, stanford-nlp, android-library, stanford-nlp-server

I tried to use `standfordNLP` libraries in `Android`. First, I make a `function()` in `java` that uses the `stanfordNLP Libraries`, working fine. But when I added the same libraries in the `Android`, it prompt

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/demo/corenlp-brat.html
>       File1: C:\Users\Project1\app\libs\stanford-corenlp-3.6.0-models.jar
>       File2: C:\Users\Project1\app\libs\stanford-corenlp-3.6.0.jar

All libraries are

```
stanford-corenlp-3.6.0.jar
stanford-corenlp-3.6.0-javadoc.jar
stanford-corenlp-3.6.0-models.jar
stanford-corenlp-3.6.0-sources.jar
slf4j-api.jar
slf4j-simple.jar
xom.jar
xom-1.2.10-src.jar
```

All `.jar` files are dependent. On deleting anyone of them, the program will not work.Can some one guide me to some other way of sentiment Analysis in Android? Any help will be appreciative.